# Convertir MD5 de un archivo a string

Tags: c#, md5

Lo que intento es comparar el md5 obtenido de un archivo descargado localmente, con el de una respuesta del servidor. La función `Md5()` Obtiene un string sin ningún problema algo como: `0A3958F9FCBA646A2D38412A3B9FC650` pero el problema es que al comparar `Comprobar()` siempre devuelve `false` y al imprimir `md5.ComputeHash(stream).ToString()` obtengo `System.Byte[]`.

```
public bool Comprobar(string filename)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            if (Md5() == md5.ComputeHash(stream).ToString())
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: que codigo implementas en Md5() ? porque segun como apliques el encode del byte array que devuelve el hash tendras un string que puede variar

Comment: Md5() solo devuelve el md5 correcto del archivo en el servidor, no hay problema con ese método: 0A3958F9FCBA646A2D38412A3B9FC650

Comment: el tema no es que no hay problemas con ese metodo, el tema es como conviertes el byte array de hash en Md5(), porque la misma tecnica de encoding deberias aplicar cuando lo haces con el file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editado: añado .Replace("-", "") para que funcione correctamente (
iuninefrendor)
 tuve ese problema:
usa el bitconverter:
además no tengo muy clar que es "Md5()" pero supongo que es el md5 que ya tienes en formato string

```
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            if (Md5() == BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", ""))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto ha funcionado, solo que al string se le agregan "-" (guiones): 0A-39-58-F9-FC-BA-64-6A-2D-38-41-2A-3B-9F-C6-50, lo resolví con un `.Replace("-", "");` podrias editar tu respuesta para agregar el replace con el bitconvert

Comment: Pues si, ademas en mi codigo estaba asi jajja. Puedes marcar la pregunta como resuelta si te ha funcionado?

Answer (score 0):

Segun como apliques el encode del byte array que devuelve el hash tendras un string que puede variar.

Si nos basamos en este articulo

[CÓMO: Calcular y comparar valores hash mediante C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/es-ar/help/307020/how-to-compute-and-compare-hash-values-by-using-visual-c)

veras la definicion

```
static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] arrInput)
{
    int i;
    StringBuilder sOutput = new StringBuilder(arrInput.Length);
    for (i=0;i < arrInput.Length -1; i++)
    {
        sOutput.Append(arrInput[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sOutput.ToString();
}
```

el cual usarias

```
byte[] byteArrayHash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

string stringHash = ByteArrayToString(byteArrayHash);

if (Md5() == stringHash)
{
}
```

pero remarco que depende de como apliques la conversion a string en `Md5()` puede que no sean iguales los string